# Can't make changes to the default Administrator Account

Tags: administrator

Can't make changes in the default Administrator Account. I'm talking basic stuff here. Can't unlock the taskbar. Resize or move the taskbar around. Not to the same monitor or to another Which is what I want to do. I can't do other things similar to this such as changing the environment a bit. I don't know what else is blocked because I really don't spend any time in that account but if these basic functions are blocked you KNOW there are more serious things that are blocked as well.

I created a new Administrator account and it has the same issues.

I mean isn't the default Administrator's Account supposed to be able to do EVERYTHING WITHOUT verification. I am unable to make even basic changes. I can't change the view of Windows Explorer. I change the default computer view from Tiles to Details and the next Explorer window that comes up has it back at tile view. I tried to get windows to show file extensions and it won't even though I uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types" in Folder Options.

Comment: This is not a question about programming, and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  You may want to try at [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Oops sorry Joe. Didn't really know the distinction.